# Converting an NSBitmapImageRep to NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsbitmapimagerep

I'm flipping between `NSImage` and `NSBitmapImageRep`(because only `NSBitmapImageRep` lets me find-replace colors per-pixel, but only `NSImage`s can be used in a `NSImageView`/`NSImageCell`'s `setImage`). I know how to convert a `NSImage` to a `NSBitmapImageRep` (using `bitmap =  [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]]`), but I can't do the opposite of that because `TIFFRepresentation` is read-only. So, how do I convert a `NSBitmapRep` to a `NSImage`?

With hope,

radzo73

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an NSImage from bitmap data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416599/creating-an-nsimage-from-bitmap-data)

Comment: Either it doesn't, or I'm doing it wrong. I'm creating a new `NSImage` using the size and representation of my `NSBitmapImageRep`, but all I get is a blank image when displaying it :/

Comment: You have to set up `initWithBitmapDataPlanes:...` *very* carefully. There are a lot of (sometimes confusing) parameters and tiny mistakes can result in nothing, but `NSBitmapImageRep` does work. I've used it for years and years on all kinds of images. Try manually building a simple 8x8 image buffer and convert that, then work up to your images.

Answer (score 0):

All that I had to do to get back an NSImage from my modified NSBitmapImageRep was call one method:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:someSize];

[...]

NSBitmapImageRep *rawImage = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];

[code that gets and sets pixels]

[image initWithCGImage:[rawImage CGImage] size:image.size]; // overwrite original NSImage with modified one
```